# Center image on splash screen while taking into account system bars

Tags: android

On my Android app (react-native but it doesn't matter) I have a splash screen. I created `res/drawable` and added a image called "emblem.png". I then center that with `gravity` of `center` as seen in my xml here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background</item>

    <item>
        <bitmap android:gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/emblem"/>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

However this centering does not take into consideration the "top status bar" height nor the "width of 'system nav bar' when landscape"/"height of 'system nav bar' when in portrait". Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you create a layout file for this? any problem or purpose for using this?

Comment: @LalitSinghFauzdar I'm not sure how, may you please show that as a solution.

Comment: Do you have any layout created for your splashscreen activity under layout tab?.

Comment: @LalitSinghFauzdar - I don't think so, I have created a react-native app. The layout is probably abstracted away. Thanks for your attention to my question by the way.

Comment: I don't know anything about React native, if it was android then I would love to help you. Sorry

Comment: Thanks @LalitSinghFauzdar for the thought. It should be the same though, if you can please share how you did it in Android I can try to do it in RN. Here is my app - https://github.com/Noitidart/Enter-The-Gunbook/tree/master/enter_the_gunbook/android - and here is the splash - https://github.com/Noitidart/Enter-The-Gunbook/blob/master/enter_the_gunbook/android/app/src/main/res/drawable/splash_screen.xml - and here is manifest modded to use this splash - https://github.com/Noitidart/Enter-The-Gunbook/blob/master/enter_the_gunbook/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L19

Comment: Any of the links are not working.

Comment: Sharing the code.

Comment: @LalitSinghFauzdar oops - thanks so so much for your speed and to look at all the details for my help. I updated the links.

Comment: Checked all your links and googled about RN too. You have to use flexbox in RN as layouts in Android. but still sharing my code (android), maybe you can figure it out.

Comment: Thank you @Lalit for your kind comment and code share. I did a lot of research to try to get flexbox into the splash, but in RN the flexbox is only available to us after the loading screen. So I am struggling to center it with resepct to status bar with just the xml file (in RN for splash screen I can only use native android stuff)

Comment: Willing to but can't help you with that.

Answer (score -2):

**THIS IS NOT AN ANSWER, I'M JUST SHARING SOME CODE**
Layout file - **activity_splash.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0+ encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id=@+id/activity_splash"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
tools:context="com.splash.splash.Splash">
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center">
<ImageView
android:layout_width="200dp"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:id="@+id/iV"  
android:gravity="center"
android:src="@drawable/applogo"/>
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="My welcome screen"
android:textsize="25sp"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textcolor="@color/white"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:id="@+id/tV"  />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity{
private TextView tv;
private ImageView iv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
tv= findViewById(R.id.tV);
iv= findViewById(R.id.iV);
final intent i = new intent(this,MainActivity.class);
Thread timer = new thread(){
  public void run(){
try{
  sleep(5000);
}catch(InterruptedException e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
finally{
startActivity(i);
finish();
}
}
};
timer.start();
}
}
```

This is how I set a splash screen in android. Hope this helps you.